# What's the meaning of "should" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the 3rd verse in Ben E. King's song [Stand by me](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/beneking/standbyme.html):

> If the sky that we look upon
>   Should tumble and fall
>   Or the mountains should crumble to the sea
>   I won't cry, I won't cry
>   No, I won't shed a tear
>   Just as long as you stand, stand by me

In the 2nd, and 3rd line, what does the usage of *should* mean?

Does it mean "If the sky that we look upon, *are supposed to* tumble and fall" "Or the mountains *are supposed to* crumble to the sea"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of your "should" is shorthand for

> if it should come to pass that
>   *if it were to happen that*

it is not saying that the sky tumbling and falling is supposed to happen, but if it did happen the signer would not cry as long as he had his friend beside him.

Answer (score 0):

*Should* is "used in auxiliary function to express condition" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/should)).

The sky tumbling and falling and the mountains crumbling are hypothetical conditions. The singer tells us what they would do, or more specifically not do, if those things happened.